# Data cached on reloading react-native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am very new to `react-native` and `js`.
I have been having this issue for some time now.
I created a react native app that picks data from a server in form of a JSON. 
This data is then used when rendering my views.
I am currently using a static JSON file on the server having the data I want to use inside the app. 
My challenge is that when I edit my JSON file on the server, this is not reflected on the app.

This is how I change state inside my app.

```
 componentDidMount()
 {
    axios.get('link_to_my_server/names.json')
         .then(response => this.setState({ albums: response.data }));
 }
```

I have removed the link to the server to avoid disturbances but I guess what I have said makes sense.

Now my question is: How do I get my data to change inside app when I reload app after changing data inside names.json on the server?

Comment: Use componentWillMount instead of componentDidMount

Comment: Have you also checked the direct link on your server, maybe the result was cached by your server even though the JSON file was changed before?

Comment: File works well inside browser on updating it

Comment: @Paras Watts using component will mount does not solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my mistake, I was passing a json file with similar names for images on server. 
I would change the image but give a similar name as before. 
The images would never be reloaded from server on phone, they were simply catched given that they had a similar name.
The solution was to upload images with entirely different names and send the new json the app, that way the images changed as expected.